# Group with summing in SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

in a table below, I need to sum COL3 and COL5, grouped by COL2NAME.
So there will be 3 rows:

```
DC
Cred
Equi
```

... with summed values of COL3 and COL5.

How could I do it?

[image: Oracle Developer]

And here's the query from the screenshot:

```
select t.*
from (select COL1, COL2 as COL2NAME, sum(COL3A+COL3B) as COL3,
COL4 as COL4NAME, count(COL5NO) as COL5, DENSE_RANK()OVER(ORDER BY COL1) GROUPID
      from TAB
      group by COL1, COL2, COL4
     ) t
where GROUPID = 1
or GROUPID = 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So just add a `group by`:

```
select col2name, sum(col3 + col5)
from (select COL1, COL2 as COL2NAME, sum(COL3A+COL3B) as COL3,
             COL4 as COL4NAME, count(COL5NO) as COL5,
             DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COL1) as GROUPID
      from TAB
      group by COL1, COL2, COL4
     ) t
where GROUPID IN (1, 2)
group by col2name;
```